# MS Project: how to distribute remaining work equally

Tags: ms-project

I have an effort driven task which should take 20 days, to which I assigned 2 resources.

Initially, the work got distributed equally between them (10d each). During the first week of work there were some setbacks for one of the resources, and they only managed to work 3 days.
So when I update the progress, I get the following remaining work per resource:
A - 5d
B - 7d

Instead, I would like the remaining work to be distributed evenly between them so that each will have 6 remaining days.

How can I achieve this in MS Project?

Answer (score 1):

I follow the step you did under MS Project 2016, but I am sure it the same in older version. I did the following steps:

1. Create a new task with default configuration (taks type `Fixed Units` with the option: `Effort Driven` marked) with 20 days duration.
2. Under the Resource Sheet view create two resources `ResA`, `ResB` with the default configuration.
3. Assign one by one each resource to the task (don't assign both resources at the same time, otherwise it won't reduce the duration).
4. Now I have the task1 with 10 duration and with `Res1` and `Res2` assigned.
5. Under Task Usage View, right button for viewing Actual Work in the grid view
6. Assign 8 hours for W, T, F, for each resource under **Act. Work** row., then automatically it will extend the work in the same way for both resources for the remaining work.

This is the standard MS Project behavior. See the picture for more detail about the final result. The duration after assigned actual work remain the same 10 days (this is related to the task type used). If the 3 working days are instead:
 M, W, F, then the start of the activity is earlier, but the duration remains the same because it is based on how duration is calculated. For more information see the following [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/169597/proj-how-work-and-duration-are-calculated-w-assignment-changes).

The leveling can be customized via: `Resource -> Leveling Options`, you have more information [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Distribute-project-work-evenly-level-resource-assignments-59ee715d-4446-42c9-8756-4ea2a5a7e4a0).

[image: Taks Sheet View]

Answer (score 0):

I would manually edit the remaining work. If you have updated the progress after 5 days, the task duration should be 12 days.  Resource 1 will finish his/her work as scheduled.  However, the remaining work for Resource 2 shouid have been pushed to the right. Split the screen from a Gantt chart to show the Task form in the lower pane.  Format the task form to show work.  Edit the remaining work so each has 6 days.  The duration will drop back to 11 days.